# Python Openpxyl query workbook for list of contained worksheets

Tags: python, excel, worksheet

Dear Python community,

I'd like to parse a recent Excel .xlsx file with the installed Openpyxl module. I need to get a list of the worksheets contained within the workbook. How can I code that in Python?

Thank you.

Regards,

Comment: check openpyxl docs. first thing to do.

Comment: Yes, I would like to. The only reason I posted here is my lack of documentation. Do you happen to have a link to the docs ready? I read through all the examples published online, but couldn't find a document that lists the methods and properties. Thank you.

Comment: Why did you four downvote my question? I wrote a clear, concise question and stated clearly what kind of answer/help I was requesting. Have I offended anyone by not having been able or thorough enough to find the openpyxl documentation? Simply downvoting someone else's post without constructively suggesting what s/he could do better next time strikes me as rude and immature. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right code :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(r"path_excel_file\filename.xlsx")

for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    print str(sheet).replace('<Worksheet "','').replace('">','')
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Your code yields the following error:

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your code yields the following error:

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your code yields the following error: "TypeError: load_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_iterators'". Do you have a link to the documentation? I couldn't find any. Thank you.

Comment: Updated the answer @Ukimiku

Comment: Thank you. You are very helpful.